# JavaFX & Gluon : NoSuchMethod exception when it clearly exists

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, gluon

I'm trying to reference a method from an instance object to create some buttons. I have to do it this way to gain flexibility (adding buttons to a toolbar dependently of a context). My project is a GluonFX project (JavaFX + [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/), which uses a Gradle file for compilation).

Here is the function which is in charge of creating these buttons.

```
public void postInit() {
    ToolbarVerticalCtrl toolbar = getRoot().getToolbarCtrl();
    ChronologyViewerCtrl viewer = ((ChronologyViewerCtrl) _tabControllersMap.get(TAB_PATIENT_CHRON_ID).getUserData());

    Image iconPlot = new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/48px/button_plot.png").toExternalForm());
    toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconPlot), i18n("title.chronology"), viewer::switchToPlot, false, true);
    // add calendar view button
    Image iconCalendar = new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/48px/button_calendar.png").toExternalForm());
    toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconCalendar), i18n("title.calendar"), viewer::switchToCalendar, false, false);
    // add patient details button
    Image iconDetails = new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/48px/button_patient_details.png").toExternalForm());
    toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconDetails), i18n("title.patientDetails"), this::openPatientDetailsTab, false, false);
    // add print report button
    Image iconPrint = new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/48px/button_print.png").toExternalForm());
    toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconPrint), i18n("title.printReport"), this::printPatientReport, false, false);
    // add print report button
    Image iconDelete = new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/48px/button_delete.png").toExternalForm());
    toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconDelete), i18n("title.deletePatient"), viewer::deletePatient, true, false);
}
```

As you can see, `viewer` is the instance retrieved of type ChronologyViewerCtrl. The instance is **not null**.

When I run the project, I get the following error from the gradle build (I just show the most important lines of the stacktrace, and made a pastebin just because formatting is awful)

The stacktrace => http://paste.ubuntu.com/16888255/

The functions I'm refering to in the controller are these :

```
public void switchToCalendar(){
    String script = "pManager.hotSwitch( aardex.plugin.CalendarAdapter.prototype.type, pManager.plot.getScaleObj() );";
    execute(script);

    getRootTab().openTab(RootTabPaneCtrl.TAB_PATIENT_CHRON_ID);
}

public void switchToPlot(){
    String script = "pManager.hotSwitch( aardex.plugin.ChronologyAdapter.prototype.type, pManager.plot.getScaleObj() );";
    execute(script);

    getRootTab().openTab(RootTabPaneCtrl.TAB_PATIENT_CHRON_ID);
}
```

I checked many posts, cleared all the `.class` files (I guess ?), put the `public` scope to the functions, nothing changed. Ideas ? I'm becoming crazy.

Thank you

**EDIT** version of the tools I'm using :

- Gluon plugin : 2.2.0
- Gradle support : 1.3.8
- JavaFX : 1.8.0_73
- NetBeans : 8.0.2 Patch 2

**EDIT 2** The ChronologyViewerCtrl class and the Gradle file just in case :

**ChronologyViewerCtrl**

```
package ch.aardex.viewer;

import ch.aardex.business.clean.ConfigBusiness;
import ch.aardex.business.clean.PatientBusiness;
import ch.aardex.business.util.ReportDataHelper;
import ch.aardex.common.DialogFactory;
import ch.aardex.common.GUIUtils;
import static ch.aardex.common.IController.DAY_TO_MILLI;
import ch.aardex.common.ITabController;
import ch.aardex.context.CurrentDataContext;
import ch.aardex.service.persist.model.monitoring.Device;
import ch.aardex.service.persist.model.monitoring.Event;
import ch.aardex.service.persist.model.monitoring.Patient;
import ch.aardex.service.persist.model.monitoring.PatientTimeline;
import ch.aardex.service.persist.model.monitoring.Timeline;
import ch.aardex.tabview.RootTabPaneCtrl;
import ch.aardex.viewer.EmbeddedAdherenceScripting.Scriptable;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ChronologyViewerCtrl extends ITabController implements Initializable, Scriptable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ChronologyViewerCtrl.class);

    @FXML private WebView webView;
    @FXML private Label labelFrom, labelTo;
    @FXML private ComboBox<TimelineItem> cbTimelines;
    @FXML private DatePicker datePeriodBegin, datePeriodEnd;
    @FXML private Button btEditMode;

    private final CurrentDataContext _dataContext = CurrentDataContext.getInstance();
    private final ReportDataHelper _reportHelper = ReportDataHelper.getInstance();
    private final Device _device;
    private final JSBridge _jsBridge;

    private LocalTime _startOfDay;
    private String _json;
    private boolean isPlotEditable = false;

    public ChronologyViewerCtrl() {
        _device = _dataContext.getCurrentDevice();
        _json   = _dataContext.getCurrentJsonData();

        PatientTimeline pt = PatientTimeline.findPatientTimeline(_dataContext.getCurrentPatient());

        _reportHelper.setStartingPeriod(Event.Finder.getMonitoringBegin(pt).getEventDate().getEpochDate());

        _jsBridge = new JSBridge(this);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //checkIfManyTimelines();

        initDatePickers();

        _startOfDay = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(ConfigBusiness.getInstance().getStartOfDay() / 1000);

        labelFrom.setText(_startOfDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));
        labelTo.setText(_startOfDay.minusMinutes(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));

        try {
            initWebView();
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * init the date pickers by disabling some days (cells) for example :
     * - Those before the monitoring begin
     * - Those adter the monitoring end
     * 
     * also adds a listener on the cells to display the plot following the selected
     * dates
     */
    private void initDatePickers(){
        datePeriodBegin.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

            @Override
            public DateCell call(DatePicker param) {
                DateCell cell = new DateCell() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if(item.isBefore(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(_reportHelper.getStartingPeriod() / DAY_TO_MILLI)) ||
                                item.isAfter(datePeriodEnd.getValue().minusDays(1))){
                            setDisable(true);
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb");
                        }
                    }
                };

                cell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        _reportHelper.setBeginPeriod(cell.getItem().toEpochDay() * DAY_TO_MILLI);

                        setDatesToJsPlot(_reportHelper.getRelativeBeginPeriod(), _reportHelper.getRelativeEndPeriod());
                    }
                });

                return cell;
            }
        });

        GUIUtils.setDatePickerFormat(datePeriodBegin);

        datePeriodEnd.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

            @Override
            public DateCell call(DatePicker param) {
                DateCell cell = new DateCell() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if(item.isBefore(datePeriodBegin.getValue().plusDays(1)) ||
                                item.isAfter(LocalDate.now())){
                            setDisable(true);
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb");
                        }
                    }
                };

                cell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        _reportHelper.setEndPeriod(cell.getItem().toEpochDay() * DAY_TO_MILLI);

                        setDatesToJsPlot(_reportHelper.getRelativeBeginPeriod(), _reportHelper.getRelativeEndPeriod());
                    }
                });

                return cell;
            }
        });

        GUIUtils.setDatePickerFormat(datePeriodEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the patient has many timelines (parallel monitoring) or only
     * one, and deactivates or not controls following the number of timelines.
     */
    private void checkIfManyTimelines(){
        // timelines management to be checked ...
        List<PatientTimeline> patientTimelines = new ArrayList<>();

        for(PatientTimeline pt : (List<PatientTimeline>) _dataContext.getCurrentPatient().getTimelines()){
            if(pt.getTimeline() != null && pt.getTimeline().getId() != -1)
                patientTimelines.add(pt);
        }

        /*
        if(patientTimelines.size() > 1){
            for(PatientTimeline t : patientTimelines){
                cbTimelines.getItems().add(new TimelineItem(t.getTimeline()));
            }
            cbTimelines.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        }else{
            cbTimelines.setVisible(false);
            cbTimelines.setManaged(false);
        }
        */
    }

    /**
     * init the date pickers with listeners and un-selectable dates following 
     * some rules
     */ 
    public void setDatePickersValuesFromJS(long start, long stop){
        LocalDate begin = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(start / DAY_TO_MILLI);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(stop / DAY_TO_MILLI);

        if(begin.isAfter(end))
            end = begin.plusDays(1);

        datePeriodBegin.setValue(begin);
        datePeriodEnd.setValue(end);
    }

    /**
     * sets the period begin / end for the chronology plot, relative to the
     * origin which is the begin of the monitoring.
     * 
     * Origin + x days = begin, where x > Origin
     * Origin + y days = end, where y > x
     * @param relativeBegin The beginning of the period relative to the origin
     * @param relativeEnd The end of the period relative to the origin
     */
    private void setDatesToJsPlot(long relativeBegin, long relativeEnd){
        execute("window.pManager.plot.updateXScale(" + relativeBegin + "," + relativeEnd + ");"
              + "window.pManager.plot.update();");
    }

    /**
     * Sets the beginning and the end of a period to be calculated
     *
     * @param start The beginning of the period
     * @param stop The end of the period
     */
    protected void setPeriod(long start, long stop) {
        LOG.debug("Period: " + start + " " + stop);

        _reportHelper.setBeginPeriod(start);
        _reportHelper.setEndPeriod(stop);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void initWebView() throws URISyntaxException {
        final URI[] jsRes = {
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.JS_RES.jq).toURI(),
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.JS_RES.jqui).toURI(),
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.JS_RES.modernizr).toURI(),
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.JS_RES.date).toURI(),
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.JS_RES.adx).toURI()
        };
        final URI[] cssRes = {
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.CSS_RES.style).toURI(),
            getClass().getResource(JSConfig.CSS_RES.control).toURI()
        };
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        // create the callback
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
                        if (jsobj.getMember("loadRes").equals("undefined")) {
                            execute(JSConfig.JS_TRIGGER);
                            for (URI js : jsRes) {
                                execute("loadRes('" + js + "', 'js')");
                            }
                            for (URI css : cssRes) {
                                execute("loadRes('" + css + "', 'css')");
                            }
                        }
                        if (jsobj.getMember("javafx").equals("undefined")) {
                            jsobj.setMember("javafx", _jsBridge);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        engine.load(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/viewer/viewer.html").toExternalForm());
    }

    /**
     * Executes the web engine to display the plot
     *
     * @param script The script to be executed by the web engine
     */
    public void execute(String script) {
        webView.getEngine().executeScript(script);
    }

    protected void defineAdherenceComputation() {
        IAdherenceScripting script = new EmbeddedAdherenceScripting( this );
        script.generalAdherence();
        script.contextAdherence();
        script.keyFeatures();
    }

    /**
     * Displays the plot by executing a script on the web engine and by
     * providing the JSON data
     */
    public void displayPlot() {
        JSConfig.saveJson(_json, "data.txt");
        try {
            final String SN = _device.getSerialnumber();
            LOG.debug("SN: " + SN);
            //snLabel.setText(SN);

            LOG.debug("JSON: " + _json);
            defineAdherenceComputation();
            webView.getEngine().executeScript("window.runPlot(" + _json + ")");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closePopup(){
        getRootTab().closePopup();
    }

    public void switchToCalendar(){
        String script = "pManager.hotSwitch( aardex.plugin.CalendarAdapter.prototype.type, pManager.plot.getScaleObj() );";
        execute(script);

        getRootTab().openTab(RootTabPaneCtrl.TAB_PATIENT_CHRON_ID);
    }

    public void switchToPlot(){
        String script = "pManager.hotSwitch( aardex.plugin.ChronologyAdapter.prototype.type, pManager.plot.getScaleObj() );";
        execute(script);

        getRootTab().openTab(RootTabPaneCtrl.TAB_PATIENT_CHRON_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the request to generate a new report from the reading
     *
     * @param event The event
     */
    /*
    private void printPatientReport() {
        Optional<Pair<String, String>> result = DialogFactory.getInstance(
                                                    getRootTab().getRoot().getPrimaryStage()
                                                ).createPatientFormDialog().showAndWait();

        if (result.isPresent()) {
            _reportHelper.setPatientNumber(result.get().getKey());
            _reportHelper.setPatientComment(result.get().getValue());

            getRootTab().snapshot(_json, getRootTab()::openPatientReportTab);
        }
    }
    */
    /*
    private void viewPatientDetails() {
        getRootTab().openTab(RootTabPaneCtrl.TAB_PATIENT_DETAILS_ID);
    }
    */

    public void deletePatient(){
        // init a variable for readability
        DialogFactory dialogFactory = DialogFactory.getInstance(getRootTab().getRoot().getPrimaryStage());

        ButtonType result = dialogFactory.showConfirmDialog(i18n("title.deletePatient"), 
                                         i18n("label.deletePatientDesc", _device.getSerialnumber()),
                                         i18n("label.deletePatientConfirm"));

        if(result == ButtonType.OK){
            PatientBusiness.getInstance().deletePatient(_dataContext.getCurrentPatient().getId());
            getRootTab().getRoot().initView(RootTabPaneCtrl.HOME_VIEW);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void onEditModePressed(){
        isPlotEditable = !isPlotEditable;

        if(isPlotEditable){
            System.err.println("The plot is now editable, logic in ChronologyViewerCtrl line 389");
            btEditMode.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/24px/button_check.png").toExternalForm())));
        }else{
            System.err.println("The plot is now not editable, logic in ChronologyViewerCtrl line 389");
            btEditMode.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("/ch/aardex/images/24px/button_edit.png").toExternalForm())));
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleSwitchTimeline(ActionEvent event) {
        // take the timeline selected
        // take the device
        // setDevice
        // setJson => PatientBusiness.viewerData(Patient, RegimenEvent)

        /*
        AdhTimeline adh = (AdhTimeline) ((ComboBox<AdhTimelineItem>) event.getSource()).getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getItem();
        CurrentDataContext.getInstance().setSelectedTimeline(adh);

        PatientTimeline slot = PatientHelper.getPatientTimeline(CurrentDataContext.getInstance().getCurrentPatient(), adh);
        Device device = TimelineHelper.getDeviceFromTimeline(slot, adh);

        setDevice(device);
        setJson(PatientBusiness.getInstance().viewerData(CurrentDataContext.getInstance().getCurrentPatient(), (int) adh.getId()));
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshTab() {
        Patient currentPatient = _dataContext.getCurrentPatient();
        int timelineIndex = currentPatient.getTimelines().size() - 1;

        _json = PatientBusiness.getInstance().viewerData(currentPatient, timelineIndex);
        _dataContext.setCurrentJsonData(_json);

        try {
            initWebView();
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class Delta {

        double x, y;
    }

    class TimelineItem {

        private final Timeline _timeline;

        public TimelineItem(Timeline timeline) {
            _timeline = timeline;
        }

        public Timeline getItem() {
            return _timeline;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return _timeline.getDesc().getName();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently working on this class, so please don't take in account the correctness of the code. As far as I know, there are no default methods used, even by inheritance.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*/*.jar', '*.jar'])
    retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.3.0'
    // desktopCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes("Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { /*'libs/' +*/ it.getName() }.join(' '))
  }
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'build/libs'//libs'
}

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'ch.aardex.main.Main'
}

task generateData(type: JavaExec){
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'ch.aardex.main.DataGenerator'
}

mainClassName = 'ch.aardex.main.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

I'm not really familiar with gradle, so if there is something wrong (or obsolete) please let me know, thanks !

**EDIT 3**

I finally gave up for these method references and reverted back to the state it was. As a precaution, I updated the JDK to 8u91, and know the error seems to affect another class which doesn't even has a method reference or a lambda expression ! The class is my Main class, and this is the [error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16920801/) I'm getting (line 738).

What I understand is that `retrolambda` failed to backport my Main class because of a function `checkLicence(LicenceBusiness, String)`, which doesn't exist!

Please help, I'm really stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you please try by using the latest retrolambda version? You can do that by adding the following dependency in your build.gradle file: `retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.3.0'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @Joeri, I did what you said and I got an error concerning the backporting of a class `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to backport lambda or method reference: ch/aardex/viewer/ChronologyViewerCtrl.switchToPlot()V (5)`

Comment: Can you provide more information about the ChronologyViewerCtrl class, perhaps show the entire source? Does it perhaps inherit from an interface that contains default methods?

Comment: @Joeri Sykora Please see edit, I provided the class and also the gradle file

Comment: Ok, I see you add jars from a local libs folder. You must make sure that all classes inside these jars are also backported with retrolambda to be able to use them on JDK 6. Retrolambda doesn't automatically apply on dependent libraries. Btw, couldn't you just replace the method reference in the postInit() method with the actual call: `toolbar.addNewButtonOnToolbar(new ImageView(iconPlot), i18n("title.chronology"), () -> viewer.switchToPlot(), false, true);`?

And also, what was the entire stack trace you got when using retrolambda 2.3.0?

Comment: Mmmh I guess that the other Jars are not a problem. The project was running fine until I wanted to switch some things (the calls to the referenced methods). And yeah, I didn't know about the syntax `() -> viewer.function` I'll give it a try, thanks ! Here is the entire stacktrace for the version 2.3.0 : http://paste.ubuntu.com/16891014/